# break the for statement loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, break

Why the output for this code is:

DRAW 
A WINS
A WINS
ERROR

and not

DRAW 
A WINS
ERROR
ERROR

as it supposed to be?

Why break doesn't work and doesn't give the result = 'ERROR' for string with not allowed letter "T" in strB? (strB = 'SRTR')

```
def RockPaperScissors(strA,strB):
    A_win = 0
    B_win = 0
    allowed_letters = 'SRP'

    if (len(strA) != len(strB)):
        result = 'ERROR'

    elif (len(strA) == len(strB)):

        for char in strA:
            for c in strB:
                if char not in allowed_letters:
                    result = 'ERROR'
                    break
                elif c not in allowed_letters:
                    result = 'ERROR'
                    break

        for i in range(0,len(strA)):
            if (strA[i] == 'R' and strB[i] == 'S'):
                a_win = 1
                A_win += a_win
            if (strA[i] == 'S' and strB[i] == 'P'):
                a_win = 1
                A_win += a_win
            if (strA[i] == 'P' and strB[i] == 'R'):
                a_win = 1
                A_win += a_win
            if (strB[i] == 'R' and strA[i] == 'S'):
                b_win = 1
                B_win += b_win
            if (strB[i] == 'S' and strA[i] == 'P'):
                b_win = 1
                B_win += b_win
            if (strB[i] == 'P' and strA[i] == 'R'):
                b_win = 1
                B_win += b_win   

        if A_win > B_win:
            result = 'A WINS'
        if B_win > A_win:
            result = 'B WINS'
        if A_win == B_win:
            result = 'DRAW'

    return result

print(RockPaperScissors('RP','PR'))
print(RockPaperScissors('PPP','RRR'))
print(RockPaperScissors('RPSR','SRTR'))
print(RockPaperScissors('RPS','RPSRP'))
```

Comment: You should fix your indentation. This code will not run.

Comment: Please re-indent your code. Or better: copy your original code, paste it here (replacing your current attempt), then select all the pasted code and use the `{}` button on the tool bar to have the editor handle the indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break only break the current loop. What you want to do is not break but return directly that there was an error.

```
for char in strA:
    for c in strB:
        if char not in allowed_letters:
            return 'ERROR'
        elif c not in allowed_letters:
            return 'ERROR'
```